# collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath with sending images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i am showing images in collection view. when i am selecting particular cell the detailed image will show in another viewcontroller. the delegate method is didSelectItemAtIndexPath. please help me.

```
recipeImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img2.png", @"img.png", @"img1.png", @"img3.png", @"img4.png", @"img5.png", @"img6.png", @"img7.png", nil];

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView1 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView1 dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this Question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393359/uicollectionview-and-push-to-detailviewcontroller-using-parse

Comment: please send me detailed code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {

      NSString *senderImg=[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
      NextViewController *next  = [[NextViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    next.receivedImage=senderImg;
     [self presentModalViewController:next animated:NO];
      }
```

NextViewController.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *receivedImage;
```

NextViewController.m

```
@syntosize receivedImage;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   UIImage imageDispay=[UIImage imageNamed:receivedImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

  {
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    detailVC.img= [recipeImages objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
   [self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];

  }
```